# Derive a while loop runs in $\Theta( \sqrt{n} )$

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

I know for a fact that algorithm **A** runs in $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$, but how does one derive that fact?

Algorithm **A**

```
i = 0
s = 0
while s <= n:
    s += i
    i += 1
```

Here is what I am thinking. We know that **A** is upper-bounded by O(n), as we increment $s$ by more than 1 in each iteration. We also know that it must be lower-bounded by $\log n$, as we increment $s$ with by something less than $2^i$ in each iteration. (Correct me if I am wrong, these are just my thoughts ...).

Now, what else can we say about **A**? How do we derive that its time complexity is $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time add $i$ to $s$ and increase $i$ by one, up to reach to $n$. Hence, if you find the $k$ such that $s = 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + k$ be equal to $n$, you can find the number of running loop. As $1 + 2 + \ldots + k = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, you need to solve this equation $\frac{k(k+1)}{2} = n$.

$$k^2 + k -2n = 0 \Rightarrow k = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+8n}}{2} = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$$

Answer (score 0):

After the first sqrt(n) iterations, s is increased by more than sqrt(n) in each iteration. Therefore at most 2 sqrt(n) iterations are needed to make s > n.

On the other hand, in the first sqrt(n) iterations, s is increased at most by sqrt(n) in each iteration, so sqrt(n) iterations are not enough.

This means the number of iterations is $\Theta(n^{1/2})$.

Answer (score 0):

### Process of elimination

A, perhaps, easier method to derive the time complexity is by process of elimination. This is especially the case if you get this type of question in a multiple choice exam. That said, this method is far from as rigorous as OmG's answer.

Okay, we know that **A** is upper-bounded by O(n), as we increment $s$ by more than 1 in each iteration.

We also know that **A** must be lower bounded by $\log n$, as we increment $s$ by something less than $2^i$ each iteration.

Okay, so far so good.

Knowing our [table of common time complexities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), we can deduce that the time complexity of our loop must be either polylogarithmic time ($(\log n)^2$) or a fractional power. 
We now notice that we are not dealing with polylogarithmic time as that would imply having some variables doubbeling, for instance:

```
i = 1                // O( (log n)^2 )
while i ≤ n
  j = i
  while j ≤ n
    j = 2 ∗ j
  i = 2 ∗ i
```

, which is far from what we are dealing with, so we can eliminate this possibility.

... We are left with one possibility: a fractional power, aka. a squareroot of some sort.